# CATransform3DMakeRotation hides half the UIView during animation

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, core-animation, catransform3drotate

Using the following UIView animation with CATransform3DMakeRotation, half the UIView will disappear during the transform and re-appear on completion. This only happens when theres a UIImageView behind the UIView in the view hierarchy of interface builder.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:nil animations:^{
        myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    } completion:nil];
```

The following is the view layout in interface builder

[image: Interface Builder layout]

And the animation result below.

[image]

The 2nd image is before any animation has taken place, the left half disappears. After it has shrunk then grown past the center point the right side (previous left side) reappears as shown in 4th image.

When the background image is set using

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jeans.png"]];
```

The animation completes as expected.

Comment: This also works fine when there's no UIImageView behind.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve... From the images, I see that this is a normal behavior, since you are rotating on the y-axis

Comment: The middle 2 images are at the very start and end of the animation, such as soon as the animation starts the left side disappears before any change in width. Only reappearing after the animation has completed. If that makes it clearer?

Comment: Perhaps try setting `imageView.layer.zPosition = -400`? Let me know if this works...

Comment: Yes that solved it! Thanks, what difference did that make? I guess it put it into 3D space?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the record, the answer was in my comment

```
imageView.layer.zPosition = -400;
```

Alternatively you could do

```
myView.layer.zPosition = 400; // or some number greater than width/2
```

It looks like part of the rotating view is occluded by the background view. Since it rotates around its center point, part of it passes into negative-z space, so is behind the background.

So from

```
------- imageView
------- myView
```

to

```
     / myView
    /
------- imageView
  /
 /
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. Trying to solve this problem for almost 3 hours.